# How many sections does a PASSENGER AIRCRAFT belly has? What cargo is allowed in those sections?

Tags: passenger, cargo, baggage-handling-system

How many sections does a belly of a PASSENGER aircraft has? 
Like if we take 3 cases :

1. I am travelling with a check in bag
2. A person who is not travelling himself but sending some items using cargo booking
3. A furniture company wants to send 4 chairs to a client

PLEASE TELL me if cargo of all these three cases above can go in the PASSENGER aircraft.

And will there be different sections in the belly for all these 3 type of cargos ?

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same.

Comment: You DON'T NEED to randomly yell DURING your post.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a passenger plane will have 2-3 compartments for cargo. Wide body plane usually has 1 bulk cargo, 1 forward cargo and 1 aft cargo compartment. A narrow body usually contains only bulk cargo compartment as it is too small for standard pallet load.

As to what can be loaded in what location is totally depend on discretion of the airline. They have to consider matter of load and balance of your cargo as well as other cargo. There is no guarantee that where your bag will end up no matter you travel with it or not. The difference is if you are not travel with it your cargo need more inspection to prevent sabotage.

Comment: But if I want to send a parcel somewhere and i did my booking with lets say Brussels Airlines, what will happen now? Will my cargo go in any passenger aircraft or in a cargo aircraft?

Comment: If you send a parcel separately from booking it can go either way. It may even go by truck. If you are flying and you bring something your luggages go with you.